# Weil restriction of quasi-projective varieties

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

I have the following definition of the Weil restriction: For a quasi-projective variety $X$ over a number field $K$ and any $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra $A$ we set $Res_{K/\mathbb{Q}}X(A):=X(A\otimes_\mathbb{Q}K)$.
I was wondering how one can see that this gives a quasi-projective variety, lets call it, $Res_{K/\mathbb{Q}}X$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ without using the language of schemes. I was also wondering how one can see that if we take $X=\mathbb{G}_m$ then the weil restriction is a torus over $\mathbb
{Q}$. I'm just trying to make sense of all these without much knowledge of schemes. Is this possible or am I just waisting my time?

Answer (score 2):

You can find explicit equations in the affine case in Section 4.6 of Poonen's *Rational Points on Varieties* (which you can read for incidental use for free online on his webpage, google it, it's generally excellent.)

For the torus case, the point is that if you restrict scalars from a field $L$ to a subfield $K$ and then base change back up to $L$, you get a product of the original variety you started with $[L:K]$-times with itself. Therefore, whatever the restriction of scalars of $\mathbb{G}_m$ is, when you base-change it back, you get a trivial torus, and so therefore it's a torus.